# SQL Server Create VIEW for Sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table that has the following structure:

### TABLE_A

DOC_ID | STATUS

```
   1   |   0

   2   |   1
```

### TABLE_B

PK_ID | DOC_ID | NAME | VALUE

```
 1   |   1    |  A   |   1

 2   |   1    |  B   |   2

 3   |   2    |  A   |   1

 4   |   2    |  B   |   1

 5   |   2    |  C   |   1
```

DOC_ID is the FOREIGN KEY on TABLE_B.

Then I create a VIEW so that I may more easily sort on NAME.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_MY_VIEW] AS 
    SELECT a.DOC_ID, a1.VALUE AS 'A', a2.VALUE AS 'B', a3.VALUES AS 'C' 
    FROM dbo.TABLE_A a, 
        ( SELECT DOC_ID, VALUE FROM dbo.TABLE_B WHERE NAME = 'A') a1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  ( SELECT DOC_ID, VALUE FROM dbo.TABLE_B WHERE NAME = 'B') a2 
        ON a1.DOC_ID = a2.DOC_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT DOC_ID, VALUE FROM dbo.TABLE_B WHERE NAME = 'C') a3 
        ON a1.DOC_ID = a3.DOC_ID 
    WHERE a.STATUS IN (0, 1)
```

This view will only include the rows with DOC_ID = 2 since the rows with DOC_ID = 1 do not have a row with NAME = C.  How should I modify the VIEW so that it will include all the rows from TABLE_B?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_MY_VIEW] AS 

SELECT a.DOC_ID, a1.VALUE AS A, a2.VALUE AS B, a3.VALUE AS C 
FROM dbo.TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DOC_ID, VALUE FROM dbo.TABLE_B WHERE NAME = 'A') a1 
    ON a.DOC_ID = a1.DOC_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN  ( SELECT DOC_ID, VALUE FROM dbo.TABLE_B WHERE NAME = 'B') a2 
    ON a.DOC_ID = a2.DOC_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT DOC_ID, VALUE FROM dbo.TABLE_B WHERE NAME = 'C') a3 
    ON a.DOC_ID = a3.DOC_ID 
WHERE a.STATUS IN (0, 1)
```

Look the results at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5574b/4/0

Comment: Looks good.  I am getting all the rows I am expecting to get now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.DOC_ID = TABLE_B.DOC_ID 
WHERE TABLE_A.STATUS IN (0, 1)
```

Replace * with the columns you want to display.
Include an ISNULL(Name, ) in your order by clause unless you want none matches at the top.

Comment: Oops, hang on, just read your full creation script in full, will update in a minute

Comment: Nope, still dont see what you are trying to achieve that the select statement I have written there doesnt provide, let me know if it is not what you are after.